# The reason of closing vote is missing when there is an audit

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, closed-questions

I've just seen that the reason of closing is missing in the reviewing page of closing votes.

[image]

Is it a temporary error or it's a bug?

EDIT: **Seems that only when there are audits the reason is missing.**

If I cannot upload image I will make an ASCII art:

```
Should this question be closed as: ? (less)  ┌────────────┐ ┌─────┐ ┌────┐ ┌────┐
                                             │ Leave Open │ │Close│ │Edit│ │Skip│
                                             └────────────┘ └─────┘ └────┘ └────┘
Leave Open if this question should not be closed

Close if this question should be closed for any reason; consider leaving an 
explanatory comment before voting

Edit if this question could be improved so that it does not need to be closed

Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next question
```

Comment: Wow, the uploading image doesn't work. -_- Asking a new question.

Comment: Probably broken by the new close reasons.

Comment: I've just ran into this bug as well. Questions is also marked as [closed] already if it is - [link](http://i.imgur.com/od38zoJ.png)

Comment: @Vladimir That's correct. Because it's an audit. You have to close it if you want to pass the audit.

Comment: Well I suppose it should be just a little bit less obvious. And this behavior differs from the one before the closing reasons update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some boolean logic was mixed up for review audit.

Fixed in the next build.