# Bug in close vote review audits

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

Whenever I get a close votereview  audit for which the good answer is to close the question there are no reasons listed, it simply shows:

> Should this question be closed as: **?** (more)

Comment: I've already asked this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186429/205508

Comment: Thanks.. I feel stupid, I spent 10 minutes searching through this site before asking.